# How to allow original HttpServletRequest to handle login using Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security and I would like to handle authentication by the jee container.
So the only reason for spring security is authorization. All the pre authenticated filters are configured already and working.

I created a custom endpoint to trigger authentication.

```
import javax.http.HttpServletRequest;
... 
@PostMapping("/auth/login")
public void login(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
   request.login("something", "something");
}
...
```

It seems that HttpServletRequest is wrapped by SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper. The following method (which is provided by spring boot) handles authentication:

HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.login(...)

```
@Override
public void login(String username, String password) throws ServletException {
  if (isAuthenticated()) {
    throw new ServletException("Cannot perform login for '" + username
        + "' already authenticated as '" + getRemoteUser() + "'");
  }
  AuthenticationManager authManager = HttpServlet3RequestFactory.this.authenticationManager;
  if (authManager == null) { 
    HttpServlet3RequestFactory.this.logger.debug(
        "authenticationManager is null, so allowing original HttpServletRequest to handle login");
    super.login(username, password);
    return;
  }
  Authentication authentication;
  try {
    authentication = authManager.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
  }
  catch (AuthenticationException loginFailed) {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    throw new ServletException(loginFailed.getMessage(), loginFailed);
  }
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

If authManager is null it should trigger login from the original HttpServletRequest.
But that is the thing it isn't null because of the AnonymousAuthenticationProvider and PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider attached to the ProviderManager. Is there another way to trigger login on its original HttpServletRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it by using my container servlet request in my method:

```
import com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest;

@PostMapping("/auth/login")
public void login(SRTServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
   request.login("something", "something");
}
```